# pycharm giving errors when trying to run test cases for automation

Tags: python, pycharm

I am getting errors when trying to run test cases in my pycharm.  Any help is appreciated.

I am launching my pycharm IDE. When I point to my python.exe file in the pycharm language server path. I am getting access denied for the python.exe file. I have changed the permission to have full access to the file. still getting the error.

Cannot run program => CreateProcess error=5, Access is denied

[image]

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what the java errors are?  Please share them.

Comment: The error in red looks like it's trying to use the name of a _directory_, instead of the full path to an actual _executable program_.

Comment: Also, it really helps to post errors as plain text.  The left half of that image is missing.  Maybe it had some important information?  We can't tell.

Comment: It looks like in the first screenshot, you entered a _directory_, which is wrong.  That should be the full path to the actual python _executable program_ (i.e. it probably needs something like `\python.exe` on the end)

Answer (score 0):

In Pycharm terminal enter `Get-ExecutionPolicy`. Your output should be `Restricted`. Change it using `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` or `Unrestricted`.